# Class extend Button

Tags: java, android, button

I have several buttons. I want to create a separate class. As I behold this button

```
<com.example.shoping.SettingsP.CustomButtons
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:id="@+id/SettingsButton"
                android:background="#010101"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                />
```

and class

```
public class CustomButtons extends Button {

    public CustomButtons(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomButtons(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomButtons(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

I want to create three buttons that when pressed to fill new Activity.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you precise your question this is not very clear.

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: I want these buttons to be active in all my activist, I have been in a class, not having to create in any Activity.

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about Android, but as I understand it could you not include the 3 buttons in a fragment and then include that in all your activities?

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion given by Alex is a good approach, , alternatively you can create an xml layout where you put these buttons and include this layout in all other layouts in this way

```
<include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/your_layout_with_buttons" />
```

Another idea could be this one:
you can create a class (eg MasterActivity) extending Activity. In this class override setContentView in this way

```
@Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);

        Button button1=new Button(this);
        Button button2=new Button(this);
        Button button3=new Button(this);
        /**
         * set your buttons layout params as you need
         */
        ((ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)).addView(button1);
        ((ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)).addView(button2);
        ((ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)).addView(button3);
    }
```

`getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)` gives you the root view, which must be a VIewGroup (such as LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc..)

doing this way when you call in your activities (that MUST extend MasterActivity) setContentView, the view will be shown and the buttons added based on the LayoutParams.
You can also set different LayoutParams based on the type of your root view using `insance of`

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onFinishInflate () {

        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
             ...........
        }
}
```

So I did it. Thank you!